# Why does my request object have no method `param`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm currently writing a web-app in Express, and I was hoping to make use of [`request.param`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.param) to extract parameters that may arrive either in the URL string (for `GET`) or in the request body (for POST).

I've passed the request object to a function which, among other things, performs a `req.param('email');`  However, this snippet throws the following error:

```
TypeError: Object #<ServerResponse> has no method 'param'
    at read_url_params (/home/louist/Documents/node/socialube/modules/user_verif.js:50:63)
    at /home/louist/Documents/node/socialube/modules/user_verif.js:43:20
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/home/louist/Documents/node/socialube/modules/user_verif.js:73:13)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/home/louist/Documents/node/socialube/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:177:8)
    at Promise.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Promise.emit (/home/louist/Documents/node/socialube/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:84:38)
    at Promise.fulfill (/home/louist/Documents/node/socialube/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:97:20)
    at /home/louist/Documents/node/socialube/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1394:13
    at model.Document.init (/home/louist/Documents/node/socialube/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:250:11)
    at completeOne (/home/louist/Documents/node/socialube/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1392:10)
```

I've tried including the bodyParser middleware, but to no avail.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please post the code that produces that error

Answer (score 5):

`param` is a [method on `req`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.param), not `res`.

Comment: Ugh, looks like I must have inverted `req` and `res` somewhere -__-.  Thanks for spotting that! =)